# How to call $urlRouterProvider.otherwise() after loading JSON file?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a project based on ionic and angular js. I am loading JSON file which contains some JSON data in key-value pair. What I want to achieve is I have to call $urlRouterProvider.otherwise() method after json file is loaded completely. Following is the code which I have tried but it does not work for me. I have tried putting console in 'defaultRoute' function it is getting executed but '$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/myjobs')' this line doesn't work.The following code is present  in app.config function. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$.getJSON('js/constants/'+lang+'.json')
        .then(function(response) {
       $translateProvider.translations(window.localStorage['deviceLanguage'],response);
       defaultRoute($urlRouterProvider);
              }, function(response) {
                  //$translate.use('en');
      });


function defaultRoute($urlRouterProvider){
             if(window.localStorage['userData']) {
        var access_token = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['userData']).access_token;
        if(access_token){
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/myjobs');
        }else{
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
        }
   }else{
       console.log("in line 282");
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
   }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but what you can do is add a timeout around the getJSON code, that will ensure it is run first.

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise doesn't work in setTimeout function

Comment: using the `$timeout` provided by angular?

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you are **running an async method in the config phase**.

**AngularJS lifecycle** is splitted in **2 phases**, **config** (where you can use providers, but not services because these are not yet registered), **and run** (where you cannot use providers, but you can use services and in general is equivalent to the main function).

The run phase starts when config phase has finished, and **config phase do not wait for any async process**, so what is happening is that **when your JSON get promise is solved your config phase has already finished** (so any provider config you try to do in your promise success callback do not really config anything).

So in short, **you cannot use $urlRouterProvider.otherwise() passing the result of an async call, like your getJson method.**

A couple alternatives to what you are trying to do (redirect user depending on auth) are:
[angular ui-router login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication) and [angularjs redirect to login page if not authenticated with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744582/angularjs-redirect-to-login-page-if-not-authenticated-with-exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `$state.go('someState')`

You would want your code to look like this:

```
if(access_token){
            $state.go('myJobs'); // where myJobs is the state correlated with your url 'tabs/jobs'
        }else{
            $state.go('login'); // or whatever the state name is that you have for 'login'
        }
   }else{
       console.log("in line 282");
        $state.go('login');
   }
```

Comment: I have tried using $state.go(). but it gives error '$state is not defined'.

Comment: are you defining $state in your controller?

Comment: I have all the routes in app.config function. I want to use $state in same function. can I use it?

Comment: you should be able to.

Comment: Let me know if that works for you. If you run into problems please make a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send the user to different routes conditionally, use `$state.go('route.path')` instead of updating the `.otherwise()` configuration. For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',['ionic']);

app.controller('$scope', '$state','$http', [function($scope, $state, $http){
   $http.get('my/api/path')
   .then(function(response){
        if(response.authenticated){
            $state.go('secret.route');
        } else {
            $state.go('public.route');
        }
   });
}]);
```