# How to redirect to login page if AbpAuthorize is failed in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I have modified the asp.net boilerplate mvc template css, but somehow, I might mess up with the code. Now if the user is not logged in/not authorized, the error pops out, click ok, instead of redirecting to the login page, it redirects to the default $urlRouterProvider in the app.js. Here is part of the app config:

```
    app.config([
    '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$qProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $qProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);


        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/Account/Login',
                templateUrl:'/Views/Account/Login.cshtml'
            })
           .state('dashboard', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                data: { pageTitle: '' }
            })
]);
```

Can any one please explain what happens behind the scenes? What is the magic code that redirects the user to the login page regardless of what you defined in the angularjs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744582/angularjs-redirect-to-login-page-if-not-authenticated-with-exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of search, I found out the reason why it did not work is because the response is not handled by HandleUnauthorizedRequest method. It is supposed to redirect to the path you defined in the startup when receiving 401 unauthorized status.

And why it did not trigger the HandleUnauthorizedRequest is because I removed the AbpMvcAuthorize in Home controller.